# How to change my query with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT N.CodOperazione,DataOperazione,N.Descrizione,Imponibile,Iva,
Totale,CA.CodConto,TotalePubblico 
FROM NotaSpese N LEFT JOIN  Conti CA ON(N.CODCONTO = CA.CodConto) 
LEFT JOIN CONTI_BANCARI_X_OPERAZIONI CO ON (N.CodOperazione = CO.ID_SPESA) 
INNER JOIN CONTI_BANCARI C ON (CO.ID_CONTOBANCARIO = C.ID)  AND C.Tipologia_Conto ='Pubblico'  
ORDER BY DataOperazione DESC
```

I want to know the all record into NOtaSpese Table also if there aren't any record in the others tables.
I have any records into NotaSpese table, but the query have an empty set

> EDIT
>   I think the error is in this point

```
C.Tipologia_Conto ='Pubblico'
```

because if I remove it, the result set is not empty